# CGAL in VS2015, error: incomplete type not allowed

Tags: c++, cgal

I'm a newbie to CGAL, and just installed CGAL 4.8 in a Windows 8 machine, the IDE is VS 2015. I tried to compile the code from a [tutorial](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Manual/introduction.html), but it doesn't work as it shows `error: incomplete type not allowed`. I tried out the same code in a Mac and it worked out fine. Can someone give some possible explanations? Thanks.

Comment: Did your compiler report a file name and line number where the error occurred? If so, please edit your question to include this.

Comment: Did you build the CGAL libs with cmake? The same question for the example?